# How to fix unknown broken link error in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, links, crawl-errors, permalinks

I've been working on a client website and found that there are broken links. I have fixed most of the links. Most of the broken links are generated from comments. So I fixed them. But still when I looked at Google Webmaster's crawl errors report, I found that there are some unknown links that are broken. Below is the sample link.

```
http://www.example.com/page/28/?fp=Twi%2F%2BHPwpi0h%2BBLrRBkxr3g%2BDZqT3dMQEyZoMB9Vyr8a32tVIcV8TXacqTSIan7Hptmo3Cu2yK%2BaCpwqw3FyfQ%3D%3D&prvtof=%2BqlsYAG0dA4qBx1hwWeIQmT3nye0uCkq%2BMLt2Xqr054%3D&poru=yUrkHSWnV4mif2swfPf6mrVD0%2FYKFgqtO2zieP4S9nRA3akMh0suIh%2FGpO2zI%2Fqx
```

There is another broken link like `http://www.example.com/page/37`.

Google Webmaster Tools says that homepage is linked to the above link but that's not true. Not even a single link is linked to that pagination URL.

I'm unable to find this link, and I even checked this with *Broken Link Checker* WordPress plugin but unable to find any solution. Please tell me why this is being produced and how to fix it?

Also please tell me how much time it takes to update Google Webmaster's crawl errors report?

Answer (score 1):

A better program in my opinion to check links is Xenu link sleuth. Try it against your site. From the time Google crawled your site showing those URL's have you deactivated or uninstalled any plugins? Have you changed templates? Or cleaned up the site by removing pages? There's no specific length of time before Google re-crawls your website. Times differ from when they actually visit the pages on your site, to indexing, and caching those pages. And just because they've visited you doesn't mean they'll re-index that page. The best you can do is update the content on the page with relevant new material, update your sitemap files and notify Google again through GWT.

Comment: I have removed some posts to clean site. No, I have not removed any plugin. My client had changed his website theme two month ago.